# Referencing to a label redirects somewhere else

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

I'm having some problem with the `\ref` command I never had. And I guess it's caused by my own style created for definition's box and similars (token from [Breaking Page with Boiboites Package TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146666/breaking-page-with-boiboites-package-tikz/545447#545447)).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

%I HOPE THERE'S NO MISSING PACKAGES OR CONFLICTING COMBINATIONS.

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish, activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}


\usepackage{ntheorem} %Para crear estos nuevos comandos.
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins}


\newcounter{ndefi}[chapter] %Counter created for definitions.

%Creating little box for the definition.
\newcommand{\defitit}{  
    \node[fill=green!20,    
    rounded corners,        
    draw=black,             
    text=black,             
    line width=1pt,         
    inner sep=4pt,          
    anchor=west,            
    xshift=12pt]            
    at (frame.north west){\bfseries Definición \stepcounter{ndefi} \thechapter.\thendefi -.};
}

%Creating the big box for the definition.
\newtcolorbox{defi}{    
    enhanced,               
    overlay unbroken and first={\defitit},   
    colframe=green,         
    boxrule=1pt,            
    arc=3mm,                
    breakable,              
    top=15pt,               
    before=\vskip18pt,      
}


\begin{document}
\chapter{El capítulo fantasma de las cosas de prueba.}
\section{Donde las cajas de definición y demás se prueban.}

\begin{defi}[Prueba de título] \label{probando1}
    Probando, probando... 1, 2, 3...
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}\label{probando2}
    Probando, probando... 1, 2, 3...
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}
    Probando, probando... 1, 2, 3...
\end{defi} \label{probando5}

\label{probando6}\begin{defi}
    Probando, probando... 1, 2, 3...
\end{defi}


Trying the references of definitions \ref{probando1}, \ref{probando2}, \ref{probando5} and \ref{probando6}.
\end{document}
```

Wherever I fit the label, the reference works badly, just showing the section and referencing to it. I guess the problem is on the enviroment I created to make those boxes, but I have no idea. Or maybe the problem is I must use something different to `\label` or `\ref`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label has to be given as an option to the `tcolorbox`.

Here's a suggestion also for coping with the title.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}


%\usepackage{ntheorem} %Para crear estos nuevos comandos.
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins}


\newcounter{ndefi}[chapter] %Counter created for definitions.
% delay the redefinition because otherwise tcolorbox would override it
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thendefi}{\thechapter.\arabic{ndefi}}}

%Creating little box for the definition.
\newcommand{\defitit}[1]{%
    \node[fill=green!20,
    rounded corners,
    draw=black,
    text=black,
    line width=1pt,
    inner sep=4pt,
    anchor=west,
    xshift=12pt]
    at (frame.north west){\bfseries Definición \thendefi.#1\unskip};
}

\providecommand{\thisdefititle}{}
%Creating the big box for the definition.
\newtcolorbox[use counter=ndefi]{defi}[1][]{
    dtitle/.store in=\thisdefititle,
    enhanced,
    overlay unbroken and first={\defitit{ \thisdefititle}},
    colframe=green,
    boxrule=1pt,
    arc=3mm,
    breakable,
    top=15pt,
    before=\vspace{18pt},
    #1,
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{El capítulo fantasma de las cosas de prueba.}
\section{Donde las cajas de definición y demás se prueban.}

\begin{defi}[dtitle=Prueba de título,label=probando1]
    Probando, probando... 1, 2, 3...
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}[label=probando2]
    Probando, probando... 1, 2, 3...
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}[label=probando3]
    Probando, probando... 1, 2, 3...
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}[label=probando4]
    Probando, probando... 1, 2, 3...
\end{defi}

Trying the references of definitions 
\ref{probando1}, \ref{probando2}, \ref{probando3} and \ref{probando4}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd avoid the `activeacute` option that nowadays is mostly obsolete since you can directly input accented characters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's been really useful and you have even fixed the issue I had to make optional names for titles. It took me a while to (more or less) understand the code and make the edition well.