# File `boiboites.sty' not found

Tags: errors

I am working with `Texifier`. I am getting this error: root.tex
LaTeX Error: File `boiboites.sty' not found.

This is because I was trying to use this package:

`\usepackage{boiboites}`

My entire code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{boiboites}

\newboxedtheorem[boxcolor=orange, background=blue!5, titlebackground=blue!20,
   titleboxcolor = black]{theo}{Théorème}{test}

\begin{document}
\begin{theo}[Loi des grands nombres]
  Soit $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ une suite de variables aléatoires réelles
  indépendantes identiquement distribuées telles que $X_1 \in L^1$. Alors :
  $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \overset{\textnormal{p.s.}}{\longrightarrow}
  \mathbb{E} (X_1) .$$
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please try to give sensible tags, what has this to do with biblatex?

Comment: there is no package of that name in texlive or ctan, where have you seen it used?

Comment: Biblatex is bibliographic facilities by Latex. Since it is related, I tagged it.    

The package does exist. This was discussed in another one of my questions which you closed and linked. If you don't recall, it is the bounding box...

Comment: biblatex is a specific package for handling citations. there is no indication that this question is about bibliographies in general or about `\usepackage{biblatex}` bounding boxes are certainly unrelated to biblatex

Comment: Oh, ok I see. My fault. I think I mixed it up for another package. But back to the question

Comment: if you go `\usepackge{bjhjhjhgjjk}` you will get a package not found error. Why do you expect that name to work?

Comment: Please take a took at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146666/breaking-page-with-boiboites-package-tikz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148119/discussion-between-ashwin-fernandez-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: you should have put that in the question:-) welcome to the web, a package from a non standard site 10 years ago is no longer available. That is is hardly a surprise. here https://web.archive.org/web/20180215041421/http://alexisfles.ch/en/latex/boites1.html but why use code so unsupported

Comment: I am sorry, Please be patient with me. I am a beginner in Latex and I am finding it very difficult to write a simple document although others may not agree.

Comment: if you are  a beginner why use unsupported non standard code briefly available on some website 10 years ago, that is just making things difficult.

Comment: Please don't rollback useful edits by other users. The edits made to your question were completely reasonable.

Comment: but it removed the fact that I was working in a Mac machine..?

Comment: @AshwinFernandez Not that relevant, frankly. But even if you wanted to add that back, you should just add that, not go back to the previous version which had no code formatting etc.

Comment: People seem very interested in the formatting but not actually answering this question....

Comment: We have answered the question multiple times in the comments and chat. And there is an answer given. The answer is don't use old packages that aren't part of the standard distribution.

Comment: But what if you wanted to?

Comment: why is the fact that you have a mac remotely related to your question?  I answered it not needing to mention any operating system.

Comment: "people seem very interested in the formatting but not actually answering this question" ???? why do you say that when I gave you a direct download link for the missing package in my answer?

Answer (score 3):

The package has never been part of supported distributions.

If you *really* need it the internet archive has snapshots,eg

https://web.archive.org/web/20171225020925/http://alexisfles.ch/files/latex/boiboites/boiboites.sty

Comment: There is a replacement package by the same author https://github.com/alexisflesch/xeboiboites/tree/master but it's still 7 years old and not part of TeX Live. So it should similarly be avoided.

Comment: I don't get why it should be. I mean, if it works it works.

Comment: you have already had to ask how to even find it which isn't a good start. Why use some code no one has used for a decade rather than a current packge that's being used and tested by millions of users?@AshwinFernandez